# Push UIViewController from UICollectionView programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I know it's a dummy request but I'm stuck in it from yesterday (It's my first time to use programmatically method).

I have `ViewController` that contains `UITableView`, and the `UITableView` has `UICollectionView` init.

What I want to do, to push a new `UIViewController` when I click on `UICollectionView`. I tried using push from `navigationController` but it didn't work.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
        navigationController.show(vc, sender: nil)        
    }
```

**CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell:**

```
class CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UITableViewCell, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {

    let navigationController = UINavigationController()

    let categories: [String] = [
        "Main course",
        "Beef",
        "Chicken",
        "Seafood",
        "Vegetarian",
        "Breakfast",
        "Side dish",
        "Drink",
        "Sauce",
        "Soup",
        "Snacks",
        "Dessert"
    ]

    let categoriesImages: [UIImage] = [
        UIImage(named: "maincourse")!,
        UIImage(named: "beef")!,
        UIImage(named: "chicken")!,
        UIImage(named: "seafood")!,
        UIImage(named: "vegetarian")!,
        UIImage(named: "breakfast")!,
        UIImage(named: "sidedish")!,
        UIImage(named: "drink")!,
        UIImage(named: "sauce")!,
        UIImage(named: "soup")!,
        UIImage(named: "snacks")!,
        UIImage(named: "dessert")!
    ]

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        layoutUI()
        selectionStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = .clear
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var containerView: UIView = {
        let containerView = UIView()
        containerView.backgroundColor = .clear
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return containerView
    }()

    lazy var categoriesNameLabel: UILabel = {
        let categoriesNameLabel = UILabel()
        categoriesNameLabel.text = "Categories"
        categoriesNameLabel.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        categoriesNameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        categoriesNameLabel.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        categoriesNameLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return categoriesNameLabel
    }()

    lazy var seeAllCategoriesButton: UIButton = {
        let seeAllCategoriesButton = UIButton()
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitle("See all", for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.setTitleColor(.CustomGreen(), for: .normal)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        seeAllCategoriesButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        seeAllCategoriesButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(test), for: .touchUpInside)
        return seeAllCategoriesButton
    }()

    @objc func test() {
        print("Test worked")
    }

    lazy var collectionView: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        collectionView.backgroundColor = .clear
        collectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        collectionView.register(CategoriesCollectionViewCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell")
        return collectionView
    }()

    func setupContainerViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 8),
            containerView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            containerView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
            containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0)
        ])
    }

    func setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            categoriesNameLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
            categoriesNameLabel.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.centerYAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            seeAllCategoriesButton.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
            seeAllCategoriesButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func setupCollectionViewConstraints() {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: seeAllCategoriesButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: 0),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 16),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -16),
        ])
    }

    func addSubviews() {
        addSubview(containerView)
        containerView.addSubview(categoriesNameLabel)
        containerView.addSubview(seeAllCategoriesButton)
        containerView.addSubview(collectionView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        addSubviews()
        setupCollectionViewConstraints()
        setupContainerViewConstraints()
        setupCategoriesNameLabelConstraints()
        setupSeeAllCategoriesButtonConstraints()
    }

}


extension CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return categories.count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesCollectionViewCell
        cell.categoriesImage.image = categoriesImages[indexPath.row]
        cell.categoryName.text = categories[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
        navigationController.show(vc, sender: nil)
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        let w: CGFloat = self.frame.width * 0.4
        let h: CGFloat = collectionView.frame.size.height - 6.0
        return CGSize(width: w, height: h)
    }

}
```

**HomeView that contains `UITableView`:**

```
class HomeView: UIView {

    var recipes: Recipes?
    var recipesDetails = [Recipe]()
    let indicator = ActivityIndicator()

    let categories = ["italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food", "italian food", "chinese food", "korean food"]

    override init( frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        layoutUI()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    lazy var foodTableView: UITableView = {
        let foodTableView = UITableView()
        foodTableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        foodTableView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        foodTableView.delegate = self
        foodTableView.dataSource = self
        foodTableView.register(CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell")
        foodTableView.register(HomeTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell")
        foodTableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        foodTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 100
        foodTableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
        foodTableView.separatorStyle = .none
        return foodTableView
    }()

    func setupFoodTableView() {

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            foodTableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor),
            foodTableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor),
            foodTableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor),
            foodTableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }

    func addSubview() {
        addSubview(foodTableView)
    }

    func layoutUI() {
        indicator.setupIndicatorView(self, containerColor: .white, indicatorColor: .customDarkGray())
        addSubview()
        setupFoodTableView()
        fetchData()
    }

    func fetchData() {
        AF.request("apilink.com").responseJSON { (response) in
            if let error = response.error {
                print(error)
            }
            do {
                if let data = response.data {
                    self.recipes = try JSONDecoder().decode(Recipes.self, from: data)
                    self.recipesDetails = self.recipes?.recipes ?? []
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.foodTableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }

            } catch {
                print(error)
            }
            self.indicator.hideIndicatorView(self)
        }
    }

}

extension HomeView: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 3
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if section == 0 {
            return 1
        } else if section == 1 {
            return 1
        } else {
            return recipesDetails.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! PopularRecipesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
            cell.collectionView.reloadData()
            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomeTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! HomeTableViewCell
            let url = URL(string: recipesDetails[indexPath.row].image ?? "Error")
            cell.foodImage.kf.setImage(with: url)
            cell.foodTitle.text = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].title

            if let readyInMin = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].readyInMinutes {
                cell.cookingTimeInfoLabel.text = "\(readyInMin) Minutes"
            }

            if let pricePerServing = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].pricePerServing {
                cell.priceInfoLabel.text = "$\(Int(pricePerServing))"
            }

            if let serving = recipesDetails[indexPath.row].servings {
                cell.servesInfoLabel.text = "\(serving)"
            }

            return cell
        }

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if section == 2 {
            return "Random recipes"
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.9568627451, green: 0.9568627451, blue: 0.9568627451, alpha: 1)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-DemiBold", size: 16)
        (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = .customDarkGray()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 30.0
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            return 130
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            return 180
        } else {
            return UITableView.automaticDimension
        }

    }

}
```

HomeViewController:

```
    class HomeViewController: UIViewController {

    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    let leftMenuNavigationController = SideMenuNavigationController(rootViewController: SideMenuTableViewController())

    lazy var mainView: HomeView = {
        let view = HomeView(frame: self.view.frame)

        return view
    }()

    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        view = mainView
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        .lightContent
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
        setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
        setupNavigationWithLargeTitle()
        setupLeftSideMenu()
    }

    func setupLeftSideMenu() {
        SideMenuManager.default.leftMenuNavigationController = leftMenuNavigationController
        leftMenuNavigationController.leftSide = true
        leftMenuNavigationController.statusBarEndAlpha = 0
        leftMenuNavigationController.presentationStyle = .viewSlideOut
        leftMenuNavigationController.allowPushOfSameClassTwice = false
        leftMenuNavigationController.menuWidth = view.frame.width * (3/4)
        leftMenuNavigationController.navigationBar.isHidden = true
    }

}

extension HomeViewController: UISearchControllerDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate {
    func setupNavigationWithLargeTitle() {

        navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
        searchController.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.backgroundColor = .white
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.textColor = .customDarkGray()
        searchController.searchBar.searchTextField.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 14)
        searchController.searchBar.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
        self.title = "Home"
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.titleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen()]
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.foregroundColor: UIColor.CustomGreen(), .font: UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Heavy", size: 36)!]
        navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(systemName: "heart.fill"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(saveButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "menu"), style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(menuButtonTapped))
        navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem?.tintColor = UIColor.CustomGreen()
    }

    @objc func saveButtonTapped() {
        print("OK")
    }

    @objc func menuButtonTapped() {
        self.present(leftMenuNavigationController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

}
```

All I want to push the new ViewController.

Comment: example to get UIViewController : let wKWebViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "WKWebViewController") as? WKWebViewController

Comment: @Ahmed if you are not using storyboards what are you using?

Comment: @AyAz programmatically UI

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz so You have a `UITableView` then inside it you have `UICollectionView` as one of the row in tableView ? Am I right ?

Comment: Hey try my approach mentioned in the answer below. It  should work.

Comment: hey the approach you have taken is really buggy. Still, I think that in case you still wanna proceed with the same, then in your original code loop through the superviews till you reach HomeViewController and push the next viewController then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you should suppose to use a `protocol` for this !

Follow these steps

Initially you need to make a protocol in your `CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell:`

```
protocol RecipesDidselectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(data: categories?, indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

then add a property

```
weak var recipesDidselectActionDelegate: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate?
```

Then inside the `didSelectItemAt`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    recipesDidselectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(data: categories[indexPath.item], indexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Likewise You need to implement a protocol in `HomeView`

```
protocol HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: class {
    func recipesSelectionAction(data: categories?, indexPath: IndexPath)
}
```

then add a property

```
weak var homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?
```

Then you should make the following delegate in `HomeView` like below

```
extension HomeView: RecipesDidselectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(data: categories?, indexPath: IndexPath) {
            homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate?.recipesSelectionAction(data: data indexPath: indexPath)
    }
}
```

and also Add delegate in your cell

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell
        cell.recipesDidselectActionDelegate = self
        cell.collectionView.reloadData()
        return cell
    }
    ....// other cells
}
```

Then at last in your `HomeViewController`, you need to add delegate

```
var mainView: HomeView = {
        let view = HomeView(frame: self.view.frame)
        view.homeViewDidSelectActionDelegate = self
        return view
    }()
```

then the delegate function in `HomeViewController`

```
extension HomeViewController: HomeViewDidSelectActionDelegate{
    func recipesSelectionAction(data: categories?, indexPath: IndexPath) {
            // Here you can push your destination View Controller 
            let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
            navigationController.show(vc, sender: nil)
    }
}
```

This should work for sure!

Comment: `data: categories?` there is an error in it _Use of undeclared type 'categories'_

Comment: It is because the data `categories` is only declared in `CategoriesTableViewCellCollectionViewCell` So its showing the error! If u don't want to pass the data to your `HomeViewController `. You can just remove the `data: categories?` from all functions ! It will work

Comment: Thank you, it works, but there is an issue with navigationController. Can you tell me why there is an issue? https://youtu.be/eNUhXcAlSfc

Comment: if the answer worked, Please do accept and upvote it ! @AhmedAbdElaziz let me check issue regarding navigationController !

Comment: Where do you configure your navigation bar in `RecipesTableViewDetails` ?

Comment: In `viewDidLoad` like `navigationController?.navigationBar.isHidden = false`

Comment: Okay ! I have checked the video, Can you please let me know what issue you are facing regarding navigation ?

Comment: It's the lag when I click on `UICollectionViewCell` to go to `RecipesTableViewDetails`

Answer (score 0):

Your tableCell doesn't have a navigationController. You need to call this code in the ViewController.

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }
```

set the CollectionViewDelegate to self in your `cellForRowAtIndexpath` method

```
cell.collectionView.delegate = self.superclass as? HomeViewController
```

You can just change the extension declaration to the following

```
extension HomeViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource
```

Comment: But I'm not using Storyboard

Comment: okay so instantiate the RecipesTableViewDetails as you were. But you need to call the code in the view controller containing the tableView

Comment: The view that contains UITableView inherits from UIView, not `UIControllerView`, I added the class.

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz you can't push UIview you just need to add as subview in your mainView.

Comment: So @AhmedAbdElaziz where the `HomeView` resides ? in a Cell or ViewController ?

Comment: @AhmedAbdElaziz your HomeView is like UIView - so it doesn't reside in Cell or not in ViewController until and unless you are not adding in any UIviewController or an other view as subView.

Comment: @AyAz I have updated the question with HomeViewController

Comment: @Vicky_Vignesh I have updated the question with HomeViewController

Comment: Is there any reason behind using `HomeView` as a view ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at collectionview **didSelectItemAt** function

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

and don’t forget to asign collectionView delegate

```
collectionView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 0):

User closer like Inside your collectionView add button now create button action in your collectionView Cell class.

```
class CategoriesCollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell {

   var btnTap : (()->())?

   @IBAction func btntapAction() {
     btnTap?()
   }
}
```

Now inside your `cellForItemAt` method

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    cell.btnTap = {
      ()in
      let vc = RecipesTableViewDetails()
      //You can also pass selected cell data like cell.categoryName.tex
      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

     }
}
```

And last Remove `DidSelect` method

Answer (score 0):

1). Need to call `collectionView.delegate = self on viewDidLoad` method.
2). Then, 
In `selectItemAtRow`method declare `ViewController`to navigate to:-

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: <Name Of your StoryBoard>, bundle: nil)
    let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:       <Controller Identifier Name>) as! <ControllerName>
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

//  Now you can push "anyController" into navigationController just you need to check

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: <Name Of your StoryBoard>, bundle: nil)
let viewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:       <Controller Identifier Name>) as! <ControllerName>
  self.navigationController != nil{
         self.navigationController?.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)

  }else{
       // Add New NavigationController here
 }
```